# How do I enable snmp on CoreOS

Tags: monitoring, snmp, coreos

I cannot seem to find any useful info on the topic.

Furthermore, what is the best way to monitor CoreOS (we use observium).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If standard Linux SNMP metrics are most you need, you just want to deploy a container that runs SNMP daemon. For that purpose you will probably need to expose it to host's network namespace (`--net=host`, if you are using Docker) and then you definitely need to bind-mount `/proc` (with `-v /proc:/hostproc` passed to `docker run`). The only unusual thing you would need point the SNMP daemon at is the `/hostproc` instead of `/proc`.

You can probably try using the [`polinux/snmpd`](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/polinux/snmpd/) image for this purpose.

Comment: We reached the same conclusions ourselves. Thanks.

Comment: a commercial product called datadog does a pretty good job monitoring a coreos installation. using a unit definition with global set puts the datadog agent on every coreos host. the reporting is awesome, there is a free service level (up to 5 hosts).

Comment: Looks like polinux/snmpd isn't modified to use /hostproc or /host_proc ... Running strings on the snmp libs and binaries only returns /proc references. Looks like https://hub.docker.com/r/digiwhite/snmpd/ has these modifications ( and uses /host_proc/ )

Comment: I have a question, I want to build a monitoring system SNMP based for Docker containers. I should install SNMPdaemon on every Docker container? Or it's possible to have only one SNMP daemon running inside a single Docker container and providing metrics about every Docker container running outside of it?