# CoreOS Kubernetes how to monitor Node processes?

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, coreos

The flanneld process on some of our Kubernetes Nodes has been known to crash, causing strange behaviour. I'd like to setup monitoring/alerting to ensure we get notified when/if flanneld crashes. We are running CoreOS as our base OS to run Kubernetes on.

One of the design decisions with CoreOS (as I understand it) is that there should be a bare minimum of software installed on the base OS and everything should run in a Pod/container.

So, with that in mind, I'd like to run a Pod/container to monitor the host process list, to ensure that there is always a process with the name "flanneld" running and send an alert if it is not running.

However, due to any Pod/container having its own process namespace, it seems I can't run a container that has access to the host process list/tree. I've tried to run a container with "privileged: true" but no luck.

Is there a way to run a container on Kubernetes that has access to the host process list/tree?

Alternatively, is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to do? Preferably without installing software directly on the CoreOS system, rather by using a container/Pod.

Answer (score 1):

One way I've found of doing it is to mount the hosts' /proc on the container e.g. "-v /proc:/hostproc" and then periodically going through all of the process numbers listed under /hostproc and verifying there is (for example) a "flanneld" one there.

Comment: This appears to be quite a common approach (e.g. https://github.com/bhuisgen/docker-zabbix-coreos, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29281350/how-do-i-enable-snmp-on-coreos)

Answer (score 1):

Why not utilise systemd it self and make sure that when flannel process (service) dies/restarts you get email, webhook triggered or some other event ?

You can easily create drop-ins for systemd units in your cloud-config like you often do with default flannel config to augment the default service file as you see fit.

```
- name: flanneld.service
  command: start
  drop-ins:
  - name: 01-somedropin.conf
    content: |
    [Service]
    ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/somecommand
```

Comment: Yes, that would make sense. I guess I was just trying to avoid modifying the Host OS (CoreOS) at all, for the reasons that I'm worried the changes will get "wiped" on CoreOS upgrade and generally have to be maintained, versioned etc...

Really wanted to have the solution run in a Pod/container on top of the host to make it so that all we have to worry about versioning/maintaining is the Docker image.

Comment: Whenever you wipe the system in any way, or even reprovision it from scratch, your cloud-config will get rerun (CoreOS reruns cloud-config on each system start) hence you don't really need to worry about it getting cleared from the system as long as you added it by means of cloud-config. I do assume that you use cloud-config, which you should keep in version controll anyway, so no problem here.

Comment: Thank you for that! Was not aware of the "cloud-config" feature of CoreOS, might be just what we're after :-)